# Xcode cant recognise iPhone when the VirtualBox MacOS can

Tags: xcode, usb, testflight, signing

so sorry if this has been answered before but I've seen several similar issues but they had fixes that didn't work for me and I don't know what else to do. I have made an app for my Uni work that I'm wanting to get tested by friends via Testflight. I am at the point where I am trying to archive it and I get the errors about no devices or provisioning profiles. Everywhere I looked says if I just connect my IPhone with "Automatically Manage Signing" active this will all be solved. But I just cannot for the life of me get Xcode to recognise phone.

In Virtualbox I have USB 2.0 selected and added the IPhone filter. I have also tried when it was set to 3.0...

[image: Virtualbox Settings]

In the MacOS the Iphone is detected as a connected USB2.0/3 device. The phone also stops charging as it connects which I assume is good since its connected to a non pyhical machine so cant charge from it if that makes sense...

[image: USB Connected]

However the Iphone isn't detected as a device in Xcode

[image: Xcode no devices found]

I just don't know why. Is there something I've missed to fix it or a way to manually do the signing as I need to archive the app so I can get started with testflight. Id appreciate any help.